# 6 Drives of 149GB aprox appearing on 1 drive of 149GB

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I was trying to open an old backup drive and seeing that it had ext3 partitions in it and I was running Windows 7, I installed Disk Internals Linux Reader. When I opened this, I got the following screenshot:

[image: Linux Reader Home Page]

When I opened the NTFS Volume 3, I had the data I wanted. But, to get the data, I need to "recover" every file individually. Is there a way to make this drive appear in Computer? Only the lettered drives in the screenshot are showing. C & E are my main disk. In partitioning tools such as Minitool Partitioning Wizard, it is as below:

[image: Minitool Partition Wizard]

I really need that data, what can I do?

Sorry, I should have stated that the column 1 in Minitool is Capacity, C2 is Used and C3 is Unused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used a recovery software called [Recover My Files](http://www.recovermyfiles.com/) and this found my files and partition and recovered them.

Answer (score 1):

Grab a Linux LiveCD, such as [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), boot into the LiveCD, mount both the drive you are trying to recover from and the drive you are trying to recover to, and copy/paste your data.

Either Ubuntu version would work (12.10 or 12.04 LTS), but watch which architecture you download.  If you have a 64-bit capable processor, either one will work, but if you are limited to a 32-bit processor, you must grab the 32-bit version.

Comment: No, this shows the same as Computer in Win7

Comment: What do you mean by showing the same?

Comment: It only shows the partitions that are in the screenshot of Minitool, the one I want is missing (the NTFS partition)

Comment: Ubuntu should be able to access ALL of the partitions on a drive, but just in case, let's run through this process: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mounting-windows-partition-onto-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 1):

Open the Win7 "Disk Management" tool (right mouse-click on My Computer in the Start menu then "Manage").
Find the partition you want. Right-click on it and select "Change Drive-letter and Paths".

Problem solved.

I guess it won't get a letter automatically because of the large number of partitions or because the next driveletter in sequence is already used for something (DVD-drive, USB stick ?).

Comment: This gives the same result as the screenshot of Minitool