# Cannot Access Hard drive from a broken PC, I have it hook to a USB adapter and can see it in in computer management

Tags: windows, hardware-failure

I am trying to get the data off of a windows XP desktop hard drive that the motherboard died on. I have a USB adapter that allows me to plug any IDE or SATA hard drive into in then plug it into my PC and access the drive. It has a separate power connector and in the past has worked great.

With this hard drive, I cannot see it when I look at My computer. When I use disk management I can see the drive, but when I right click on the drive all the options to "assign a drive letter", "convert to dynamic disk", "delete partition" etc, are grayed out.

It is a 75 GB IDE drive that shows as "Active and healthy" in computer management. I really need to get some data off of it so any ideas would be really appreciated. Is there any programs I could get? Any techniques I am not aware of etc?

Comment: Can you add the output of `diskpart`. `list disk`, `select disk 1` (or whatever number your USB drive is) and `list partition`? That will tell us if the MBR is being recognised.  (assuming MBR since it came from XP and XP only supports MBR).

Comment: Is the drive "marked active" in disk manager?

Comment: Hello,   yes its active in disk manager, I can select it is diskpart,  as disk one, when i list partion is come back as unknown, going to try a linux CD  now , any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Grab a Linux LiveCD, such as [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), boot into the LiveCD, mount both the drive you are trying to recover from and the drive you are trying to recover to, and copy/paste your data.

Either Ubuntu version would work (12.10 or 12.04 LTS), but watch which architecture you download.  If you have a 64-bit capable processor, either one will work, but if you are limited to a 32-bit processor, you must grab the 32-bit version.

Comment: Please refrain from [directly copying answers](http://superuser.com/a/536737/47225) of yours.  Make them unique and applicable to the question at hand.

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to make generic instructions that apply to both situations unique.

Comment: @Krugg just be careful and not do it all the time.  In this case it's fine IMO, but again, be careful about doing it in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your advise,  I was aware of that option but i was hoping to find some software i could run in a windows environment,  I ended up  using the linux live CD and  I could mount the hard drive and copy the data to my local C drive.    Worked great thanks.